# How to run play framework unit test in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

Currently i am tring to develop web based application using play framework in java. And i would like to write unit test and run it through Elcipse.  I tried but class not found exception appeared.  How can i achive that?Could anyone help please? i am using play framework 2.0

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unit test your code that calls out to the framework then you can do so by using an object mocking library such as [Mockito](http://gojko.net/2009/10/23/mockito-in-six-easy-examples/). You should refactor your code to isolate the touch points with the framework as much as possible into separate classes. Then you can mock the framework objects and test your code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that's what he asked for... Looks like he's just looking for a way to run the unit tests from within the IDE (ie.. by clicking the "Run tests" menu) -- as opposed to going to the CLI and typing "play test"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the ScalaTest plug-in for ecplise. You can find it [here](https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-eclipse-plugin) along with the update links for your version of Eclipse. They also mention it on scalatest.org but none of their update links are still valid.